# video cover image selector from user dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image, video

i am developing video application in that i required video cover image , that i what to select from the user,

select cover image from the user like below image

[image]
i search many times in google for custom controller but i didn't get any result, if is there any custom controller ?? or any suggestion for that it is very helpful for me

Comment: Hi @mitul, i want to implement the same functionality so can you please let me know how you have implemented "custom view" for picking up cover image ?

Comment: @AjayGabani please check ans. and  its comments you can get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actully you can get Video Thumb cover image using path of video file using Bellow code or you can get all frame of video file. But there Apple Not provide any view-controller for choose cover image Thumb for video. you have to create Manually Time at `thumbnailImageAtTime` or create you own that type of view and get thumb image using Bellow code. Hope that useful.

```
-(void) getAllImagesFromVideo
{
   imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:375];
   times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:375];

   for (Float64 i = 0; i < 15; i += 0.033) // For 25 fps in 15 sec of Video
   {
       [times addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(i, 60)]];
   } 

   [imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error) {
       if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded)
       {
           [imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image]];
           CGImageRelease(image);
       }
   }];
}
```

Above code Ref from [Get all frames of Video IOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436552/get-all-frames-of-video-ios-6) Here you have all frame image of you video. so create you own `view-Controller` as you mention image in to your question create `view-controller` like above and set all image in to horizontal `scroll-view` and select any for your cover image else you can get particular image from time using Bellow code directionally .

```
-(UIImage *)getThumbNail:(NSString*)stringPath
{
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];

    //Player autoplays audio on init
    [player stop];

    return thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: you are not add any code from video file path in method  -(void) getAllImagesFromVideo  so how get the video images ???

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436552/get-all-frames-of-video-ios-6 and also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199879/iphone-read-uiimage-frames-from-video-with-avfoundation